# ES6 imports: pick up updates to external project

Tags: node.js, typescript, gulp, ecmascript-6

We are starting a new project using angular2, typescript and gulp. For the time being our application will consist of two subprojects: a components library (which in the future might be spun off into a separate project) and the app using the component library.
The layouts of the project is going to be something along the lines:

```
/project_root
    /component_library
       /src
            /library
                /components 
                /services
                ... etc
    /application
        /src
           /app_name
               /components
               /services
                ... etc
```

The components in application will be using components from the library (but not the other way round)
We would like to have clean (non relative) imports in the app components when importing stuff from the library (we want to avoid ugly imports of the sort '../../../component_library/src/library ...etc' plus, what's more important, we want to be able to move the library code to a separate project without the need to update imports.

There are two possible solutions I see (don't like any of them):

1. Add a gulp task that would watch the component library and on every change copy the file to node_modules in /project_root
2. Some sort of simlink? so that we can point /project_root/node_modules to /project_root/component_library/src?

I'm afraid the first solution might not work well with IDE autocomplete in the application (first gulp would need to do the compilation/copying then the IDE would need to pick up the change from node_modules - this looks like something that can be really slow)
The second solution feels hacky - it would need to be repeated by everyone who checks out the code from repo.

What would be the best solution here?

Answer (score 0):

> what's more important, we want to be able to move the library code to a separate project without the need to update imports.

Ship your `component_library` *with source* and add it as a `node_module` dependency. Then when someone pulls your code they can add a git remote to `node_modules/component_library` code and work on the two projects seemlessly.

This is the approach I took with [`ntypescript`](https://github.com/TypeStrong/ntypescript).